# Constraint layout leaving space On top

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a fragment containing a layout

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="8dp"
    tools:context="tech.pkg.name.fragments.ReportFragment">

        <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
            android:id="@+id/constraintLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/typeSlector"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/linearLayout2" />

            <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
                android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
                android:background="@drawable/android_date_bgd"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/fromTextView"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                    android:text="@string/from"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/fromDateTextView"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                    android:drawablePadding="5dp"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:text="@string/dd_mm_yy"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/fromTextView"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/view9"
                    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread_inside"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/fromTextView"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/fromTextView" />

                <View
                    android:id="@+id/view9"
                    android:layout_width="1dp"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                    android:background="@android:color/black"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/toTextView"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/fromDateTextView"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/toTextView"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/to"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/fromDateTextView"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/toDateTextView"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/view9" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/toDateTextView"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                    android:drawablePadding="5dp"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:text="@string/dd_mm_yy"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/toTextView"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/toTextView" />

            </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
        </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

        <RadioGroup
            android:id="@+id/radioGroup"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.RadioButton"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView8"
            tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
            tools:layout_constraintRight_creator="1">

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/mobileRadioButton"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.20"
                android:checked="true"
                android:text="Mobile"
                android:textSize="18sp" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/DTHradioButton"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="0.14"
                android:text="DTH"
                android:textSize="18sp" />

        </RadioGroup>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_view_report"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:background="@drawable/button_bgd"
            android:text="@string/submit"
            android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/view5"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/view5"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
            android:background="@color/colorEditTextLine"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/radioGroup" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/downloadCheck"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.Checkbox"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.088"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/constraintLayout" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView8"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:text="@string/download"
            app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/downloadCheck"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.02"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/downloadCheck"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent" />
    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

it is containing in

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/fragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
```

[image]

But in the layout editor it is showing

[image]

How can I remove the spacing above?

Comment: Try this, In my case I used below code in Constant Layout
**android:layout_marginBottom="?attr/actionBarSize"**

Comment: Not working....

Comment: Not a solution, but try to set different background colors for different layouts. This way you can easily figure out which layout is causing the problem.

Comment: I tried that way and then I put this question

Comment: Actuallly fragment layout is causing the problem

Comment: Problem is with your fragment code. Layout looks fine. Please paste code where you are inflating this view. Looks like, you are dynamically adding some padding in your views.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with your Activity where you had inflated the Fragment. Actually, i tried it on My system and I'm Getting Proper result.

**Check Your `Activity`'s Layout where the  FrameLayout is Used.**

**2nd Possbility**

Check your May be Your Theme is Changing this . Check all the possibilities

[image: The Same Look Like this in My phone]

Answer (score 0):

Try  the following **code** Replacing the `ConstraintLayout` after the Spinner

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/android_date_bgd"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">
```

Comment: @KiranBennyJoseph I Had Up[dated the code. try it Please. The Date BAge Layout have a Margin top . I think That is being Displayed as the problem

Comment: But I removed that it is a change of design. Also I removed that but getting same results

Comment: @KiranBennyJoseph It is problem with some margin . Check tht please

Answer (score 0):

What happened to me was smiliar, a space on top that did not show in the editor.

The problem was not in the main layout file I was focusing on, I was displaying some fragments thru a viewpager and the margins on the editor for the pager were 0 so the editor preview did not showed a space on top. However the fragments that were being created/shown had of course a different layout file and in that layout there was a huge space on top because I erroneously thought centering the layout vertically was a good idea for some reason (mainly because I code at night before bed and sometimes im too tired lol). Since the layout height for the viewpager did not match the dimensions of the fragment I had some weird behaviors trying to position the elements of the main layout file.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing a similar problem. By looking at the code snippet in the question I saw the similarity that we both have `android:fitsSystemWindows` set to **True**. By removing this `android:fitsSystemWindows` attribute, my space at the top was removed.